# Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

tried to pass data between view controllers,but keeps getting the error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10b4e4ca8) to 'StockList.AllListsTableViewController' (0x106d963f0).
```

I have checked to make sure that I set the classes for the view controllers but it's still not working.Here is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let navigationController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    let controller = navigationController.viewControllers![0] as! AllListsTableViewController
    controller.dataModel = dataModel
    return true
}
```

[Here is my storyboard:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tILN.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to set class name to the VC in IB from Identity Inspector ( `AllListsTableViewController` )

Second use

```
let tab = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
let navigation = tab.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
let controller = navigation.viewControllers![0] as! AllListsTableViewController
controller.dataModel = dataModel
```